# Something missing with Vim - error from vimrc

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim. When I run it from the terminal I get this error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/Rob/.vimrc:
line   28:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown'
```

It still seems to run, but I'm not really doing much with it, so I'm sure I'm just not running into the error yet. What should I fix and how should I solve it?

```
Rob@Rob:~ $ cat ~/.vimrc
" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
filetype plugin on

" IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shellslash' set so that latex
" can be called correctly.
set shellslash

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

" this is mostly a matter of taste. but LaTeX looks good with just a bit
" of indentation.
set sw=2
" TIP: if you write your \label's as \label{fig:something}, then if you
" type in \ref{fig: and press <C-n> you will automatically cycle through
" all the figure labels. Very useful!
set iskeyword+=:

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown'
```

This is the result of running `apt search --names-only vim | grep install`:

```
$ sudo apt search --names-only vim | grep installed

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

vim-common/oldstable,oldstable,oldstable,oldstable,now 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 all [installed,automatic]
vim-gtk/oldstable,oldstable,now 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 amd64 [installed]
vim-gui-common/oldstable,oldstable,oldstable,oldstable,now 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 all [installed,automatic]
vim-runtime/oldstable,oldstable,oldstable,oldstable,now 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 all [installed,automatic]
vim-tiny/oldstable,oldstable,now 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Can you please list the content of your `.vimrc` file? Like this: `cat ~/.vimrc`. Please paste the content between backticks or using the codeblock option so that it keeps the formatting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I'm not sure what you mean by backticks, I'll have to look it up more, I just read " A backtick is not a quotation sign. It has a very special meaning. Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell before the main command" I'll figure out how to paste it in a codeblock now

Comment: `Rob@Rob:~
$ cat ~/.vimrc
" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
filetype plugin on

" IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shellslash' set so that latex
" can be called correctly.
set shellslash

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

Comment: " this is mostly a matter of taste. but LaTeX looks good with just a bit
" of indentation.
set sw=2
" TIP: if you write your \label's as \label{fig:something}, then if you
" type in \ref{fig: and press <C-n> you will automatically cycle through
" all the figure labels. Very useful!
set iskeyword+=:

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown'

Comment: In a US keyboard, they are the leftmost key along the numbers row, it shares key with the tilde (~). It is shaped this: `

Comment: I'm using a US type keyboard, but embarrassingly I can't figure out how to get ` ` to make it a code block just doesn't seem to recognise what's in between :-|

Comment: Please paste the output in the body of your original question, at the bottom, by editing the actual question. Use three backticks, paste the output below, and close with three backticks in the line below your paste. This will preserve formatting and make it much easier to read. If you have trouble I can edit it for you (I think).

Comment: Ah, okay how silly of me. Thanks for the tip. Done, please see the original post for the .vimrc contents, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the offending line is the last line in the file (line 28):

`Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown'`

I presume you used one of the `vim` plugin managers to get the plugin installed, and the plugin files are installed where they should be. If not, how did you install it? More importantly, the error message says `python required`. Do you have Python installed? Try:

`apt search --names-only python`

Which will show you packages that contain the word "python" in the package name (`--names-only`), and filter out those that say "installed" only (`| grep installed`). For example, if I do that on my computer, the output includes:

```
python2/eoan,now 2.7.17-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3/eoan,now 3.7.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Usually Python comes pre-installed in most Ubuntu installations, so it's good to verify that it is. No need to copy the output here, but check that python 2 and/or python 3 are installed as on mine.

Comment: Hi, I may well not have python installed. At highschool it was QBASIC/FreeBasic, then UNI was all C and matlab. So I never learnt python. what does apt search --names-only python do? I get way too many lines to paste here. I think I installed Vim from a .deb package.

Comment: Maybe I do, when I tried installing it it says it will break python 2.7. Should I purge python and try again?

Comment: BTW I think I put the line Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown' in there. I've never edited a .rc file before and I probably did it wrong, but it's not the issue with python, as I deleted the line to no avail. Cheers

Comment: Ah, OK, you should try and install any software using the supported methods, when possible, and try to avoid downloading from the web. I know it's probably too late in this case but doing so makes the software much easier to uninstall later. So try using the `apt` package manager, or Ubuntu Software Center. The command `apt search --names-only python` shows you all python packages and you can see which are installed (they'll say `[Installed]`).

Comment: How you fix this depends on how you installed vim. I just did an installation straight from the Ubuntu repositories and it works OK. So try `apt search --names-only vim | grep installed`, to see what's been installed using apt and can be uninstalled easily. What this does is list all packages with vim in their name, and filters only those that say 'installed'.

Comment: I'll add the result for apt search --names-only vim | grep installed into the original post for your review. Can you elaborate on how this shows what is installed? I am somewhat familiar with piping and grep, but it's the 'search --names-only' and 'installed' key works I'm interested in, I assume they're options for the package manager. Seems like a useful technique to learn. I understand the advantages of installing only from apt, but I want to know I have a repository which I could install an OS in a no-internet situation. Thanks!

Comment: If you've installed packages not using `apt` and from the official Ubuntu repositories, then this is more than likely how you've ended up with an unstable configuration.